# I need to show my poly count in my render for a school assignment. How can I do that using Blender 2.83?

Tags: rendering

I modeled a well for a school assignment using blender 2.83. I need to make a render which shows the poly count. I can't find polycount as an option in the Metadata to include in the render. I wonder if there is a way to include it in the render or am I going to have to add it in the notes after getting them.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174158/show-the-polycount-of-selected-objects-in-object-mode

Comment: Just add it as custom text/name in the metadata options.

Answer (score 1):

Poly count is at the very bottom right of the screen.

In the note section for metadata write the info you want and turn on "burn into image"

[image]

A different way to see statistics is to enable the overlay in the 3D viewport as shown in this post:

[Bottom Status Bar Doesn't Show Verts, Faces, Tris Information In v2.9a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177762/bottom-status-bar-doesnt-show-verts-faces-tris-information-in-v2-9a)

[image]

Here's a script to automatically write the with the selected object's stats on the metadata notes:
adapted from :

[Show the polycount of selected objects in object mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174158/show-the-polycount-of-selected-objects-in-object-mode)

```
import bpy

verts, edges, polys = 0, 0, 0
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()  # Getting the dependency graph
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    obj = obj.evaluated_get(dg)
    # This gives the evaluated version of the object. Aka with all modifiers and deformations applied.  
    mesh = obj.to_mesh()  # Turn it into the mesh data block we want

    verts += len(mesh.vertices)
    edges += len(mesh.edges)
    polys += len(mesh.polygons)

bpy.context.scene.render.use_stamp_note = True
bpy.context.scene.render.stamp_note_text = "Verts: "+str(verts)+", Edges: "+str(edges)+", Polys: "+str(polys)
bpy.context.scene.render.use_stamp = True
```

To use go to the scripting window, create a new text, paste the script and run it.