# 2.9 changed the info log position - can I put it back?

Tags: interface, customization

In 2.9, the Info Log that appears in the status bar when certain actions, such as Merge Doubles, are performed is in a new position in the right-hand side.

[image: Blender 2.9 places the info log in the bottom-right of the screen. It's being cut off.]

In 2.83.8, the info log is placed in the bottom-center. This is a place that's much easier to see while working for me, and I'd greatly prefer the info bar to be here.

[image: Blender 2.83.8 puts the info log in the center of the status bar, like a good boy.]

Can I revert the change of info bar position in 2.9 to what it's been since 2.8?
It seriously bugs me to have to look all the way over to the bottom right for a display I use very frequently, especially considering it was already in a fine spot before. This one change is the biggest reason why I've stuck to 2.83 instead of using 2.9. It drives me nuts! :C
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bottom Status Bar Doesn't Show Verts, Faces, Tris Information In v2.9a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177762/bottom-status-bar-doesnt-show-verts-faces-tris-information-in-v2-9a)

Comment: Nope. I specifically want to put the Info Log (the blue thing that appears in the Status Bar when some commands are performed) back where it was in 2.8.
I appreciate your help, though!

Comment: If you can wait until the end of November, the messages will be displayed in the center of the status bar in 2.91. See ticket [T81171](https://developer.blender.org/T81171).

Comment: If you are in a hurry you can edit `space_statusbar.py` in your current install and make the same changes as the fix in commit https://developer.blender.org/rB5e2a60a0034dc7543c868328cf971c442a0b33fb

Comment: They'll change it back? That's fantastic news! Thank you for looking into it, I'm glad this little will have an end. There's hope for the future at last! You're my hero!
I accept this as an answer to my question. I'll try to figure out how to do that edit you mentioned, too.

Comment: Er, if you posted what you just said as an answer to this question, I'd accept it. I'm not sure how to accept comments as answers, or if that's possible.

Comment: I will post it as an answer in about an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status bar will center the output of [`bpy.types.Operator.report`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report) in Blender 2.91, see [ticket T81171](https://developer.blender.org/T81171) for more information.

If you want to have this change in your current version, you can edit `2.90\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_statusbar.py` yourself and apply the same changes as the fix in commit [rB5e2a60a0034dc7543c868328cf971c442a0b33fb](https://developer.blender.org/rB5e2a60a0034dc7543c868328cf971c442a0b33fb). Make sure to keep the indentation exactly the same and don't mix spaces and tabs.

**Before (2.90.1)**

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

# <pep8 compliant>
from bpy.types import Header


class STATUSBAR_HT_header(Header):
    bl_space_type = 'STATUSBAR'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # input status
        layout.template_input_status()

        layout.separator_spacer()

        # Nothing in the center.
        layout.separator_spacer()

        row = layout.row()
        row.alignment = 'RIGHT'

        # Stats & Info
        row.label(text=context.screen.statusbar_info(), translate=False)

        # Messages
        row.template_reports_banner()

        # Progress Bar
        row.template_running_jobs()


classes = (
    STATUSBAR_HT_header,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only for live edit.
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
```

**After (2.91.0)**

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

# <pep8 compliant>
from bpy.types import Header


class STATUSBAR_HT_header(Header):
    bl_space_type = 'STATUSBAR'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # input status
        layout.template_input_status()

        layout.separator_spacer()

        # Messages
        layout.template_reports_banner()

        # Progress Bar
        layout.template_running_jobs()

        layout.separator_spacer()

        row = layout.row()
        row.alignment = 'RIGHT'

        # Stats & Info
        row.label(text=context.screen.statusbar_info(), translate=False)


classes = (
    STATUSBAR_HT_header,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only for live edit.
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
```