# Show number of Tris selected

Tags: interface

Is there a reason it doesn't show you the number of Tris selected? Seems benighted to me. I really need this feature.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bottom Status Bar Doesn't Show Verts, Faces, Tris Information In v2.9a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177762/bottom-status-bar-doesnt-show-verts-faces-tris-information-in-v2-9a)

Comment: It could possibly be scripted, but @susu the OP is right, tri count doesn't update.